# Subclipse - Checkout SVN repository into a non-root folder

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Is there any way to make subclipse checkout a repository into a non-root folder of a project. In particular, I want to checkout into folder src/wavedev rather than just to the project root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a solution to your situation, but you could use SVN:Externals

The SVN:Externals property lets you checkout an external repository within your current repository. Changing code in this external repository will update in your current project and changing code in your current project from the external repository will commit to that repository.

To set the external property in subclipse:

```
right-click your root foolder
select team > set property
From the property dropdown select "svn:externals"
```

set the value to:

```
src/wavedev  http://svn.yourrepository/wavedev
```

As far as I  know subclipse uses the same .svn folders as the svn commandline tool or for instance tortoisesvn. So if you can't get it to work with subclipse you could try this workaround

Comment: That requires that the root directory be a working copy of another repository. ATM, that isn't the case with my project. I suppose that I could just sync with a dummy repository

Comment: Moved this from being in one project to my main project (which will be in version control once I decide what to use). So might be able to use this trick.

Answer (score 1):

If your top level project isn't under version control, then you probably can't do the svn:externals trick.

However, you could work your way around it:

Check out the code you want into a new project (let's call this Project B).

In the project your working in (let's call it Project A), create a new folder (src/wavedev), but in the New Folder Dialogue, use the Advanced button to link it to an external folder in the filesystem.  You can point it to the location of Project B.

It might make more sense, though, to add Project B to the build path of Project A...?

Answer (score 0):

If your top level project isn't under version control,
        1. You could checkout the src tree in some other directory and make a soft link from   your source to the checked out folder. 
        2. Alternatively, You can checkout the src tree in some other location and configure eclipse to look for source in the newly checked out folder.

The answers above are perfectly valid work arounds, but these are just few more to the list.!